# Перенаправление на разные URL-адреса для разных ролей после входа в систему

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица users со столбцами id_user, login_user, password_user, mail_user и role. 
role - int(3). Предусмотрено 3 вида роли: 1 - обычный пользователь, 2 - модератор, 3 - администратор. По умолчанию, при регистрации, пользователь автоматически получает role - 1.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при авторизации пользователи с разными ролями попадал на разные страницы профиля. Например: админ - admin.php, user - user.php и т.д.
Собственно, проблема в том, что при авторизации role игнорируется. Т.е. авторизовался пользователь с role 1, а ему страницу role 3 выдает. Если просматривать сам код страницы, видно, что пользователь как бы и на admin.php, и на user.php.
Перерыл половину Интернета, ничего не нашел. Либо я слепой, либо не хватает логики. В любом случае, буду благодарен за помощь. 
Код index.php:

```
<?php
    $r='';
    $auth = new auth(); 
    if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
      if (!$auth->authorization()) {
      $error = $_SESSION['error'];
      unset ($_SESSION['error']);
      }
    }

    if (isset($_GET['exit'])) $auth->exit_user();
    $id_user = $_SESSION["id_user"]; 
    if ($auth->check())
    if ($role=["3"]) {
     $r.="

    (' <li><a  href='admin.php'> ".$_SESSION['login_user']."
    </a></li><li><a href='?exit'>Выйти</a></li>')";}

        if($role=["2"])
     {   $r.="

    (' <li><a  href='moder.php'> ".$_SESSION['login_user']."
    </a></li><li><a href='?exit'>Выйти</a></li>')"; } 

     if($role=["1"])
     {   $r.="

    (' <li><a  href='user.php'> ".$_SESSION['login_user']."
    </a></li><li><a href='?exit'>Выйти</a></li>')"; } 

    else {

      $r.='
    <li><a href="signin.php">Войти/Зарегистрироваться</a></li>
      ';
    }
      print $r;

    ?>
```

auth.php:

> function check() {
>
> ```
> if (isset($_SESSION['id_user'])  and isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) return true;
> else {
>     if (isset($_COOKIE['id_user']) and isset($_COOKIE['code_user'])) {
>     $db = new mysql(); 
>     $id_user=$db->screening($_COOKIE['id_user']);
>     $code_user=$db->screening($_COOKIE['code_user']);
>     if ($db->query("SELECT * FROM `session` WHERE `id_user`=".$id_user.";", 'num_row', '')==1) {
>     $data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `session` WHERE `id_user`=".$id_user.";", 'accos', '');
>       if ($data['code_sess']==$code_user and $data['user_agent_sess']==$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) {
>         $_SESSION['id_user']=$id_user;
>       $_SESSION['login_user']=$db->query("SELECT login_user FROM `users` WHERE  `id_user` = '".$id_user."';", 'result', 0);
>       setcookie("id_user", $_SESSION['id_user'], time()+3600*24*14);
>         setcookie("code_user", $code_user, time()+3600*24*14);
>         return true;
>       } else return false; 
>     } else return false; 
>   } else return false;
> }   }
> ```
>
> function authorization() {
>       $db = new mysql(); 
>       $login = $db->screening($_POST['login']);
>       $passwd = md5($db->screening($_POST['passwd']).'lol'); 
>       if ($db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE  `login_user` =  '".$login."' AND  `passwd_user` = '".$passwd."';", 'num_row', '')==1)
>   {
>       $_SESSION['id_user']=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE  `login_user` =  '".$login."' AND  `passwd_user` = '".$passwd."';",
>   'result', 0);
>         $_SESSION['login_user']=$login;
>         $r_code = $this->generateCode(15);
>         if ($db->query("SELECT * FROM `session` WHERE `id_user`=".$_SESSION['id_user'].";", 'num_row', '')==1) {
>         $db->query("UPDATE `session` SET `code_sess` = '".$r_code."', `user_agent_sess` = '".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."' WHERE `id_user`
>   = ".$_SESSION['id_user'].";", '', '');
>       header("Location: index.php");    } else {
>         $db->query("INSERT INTO `session` (`id_user`, `code_sess`, `user_agent_sess`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id_user']."', '".$r_code."',
>   '".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."');", '', ''); setcookie("id_user",
>   $_SESSION['id_user'], time()+3600*24*14); setcookie("code_user",
>   $r_code, time()+3600*24*14);
>
> ```
> }
> ```

Comment: Ужас, что это ?) Самый простой способ: при авторизации записывать тип пользователя в сессию и в файле index.php делать примерно так: если тип 1, то `выведем это меню`, если другой тип - вывод `этого меню`.

Comment: Это по тупому, но довольно простая реализация как для начинающего, плюс расширять не очень сложно в рамках небольшой системы. P.S: плохая практика формировать контент в переменной, а потом выводить его, когда-то споткнёшься и хрен найдёшь, где не закрыл тег.